# javascript with jQuery - how to change specific Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, selector

How can i change followed given HTML code via javascript and jQuery:

```
<div> <strong> unimportant text here </strong> important text here </div>
```

Goal is to change the Text in the `<div> .... important text here </div>` without touching the ...

```
<strong> unimportant text here </strong>
```

...part

Example:

**unimportant text here ** important and changed text here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/33udc/1)**

This requires having access to the parent div. I am not sure how you would like to access it, but for example, I will use an `id`.

```
<div id="d"> <strong> unimportant text here </strong> important text here </div>
```

This allows for the inner element to targeted. You should just use substring in order to select the latter part of the text

```
var AllText = $('#d').text();
var StrongElementText = $('#d strong').text();
var ImportantText = AllText.substr(StrongElementText.length);
```

*Edit*

With no way to target the element directly, it will have to be inferred (which can lead to target collision)

**[jsFiddle Demo Using Inferred target](http://jsfiddle.net/33udc/3/)**

```
$('div strong').each(function(){
 var AllText = this.parentNode.innerText;
 this.parentNode.innerText += " And Changed";
 var StrongElementText = this.innerText;
 var ImportantText = AllText.substr(StrongElementText.length);
 c[0].innerHTML += ImportantText + "<br>";//shows output
});
```

Comment: He wants to change div text I guess , not the text in <strong>

Comment: it is not possible to add a ID or Class to the HTML content.

Comment: @Chrizzldi - Then any pattern you apply will match your whole document. You can still use this pattern though, I will edit to show what that will look like generically (although not suggested).

Comment: @Travis J, well not sure if i got this one. But it looks like i have to separate all Children-Elements to edit the text and then build them all together again? There is no other way to do it?

Comment: @Chrizzldi - Since you have such a generic setup without any specific ways of targeting these elements or text, then no, there is no other way to do it. The html is not formatted to support proper indexing and the side affect is having to do these types of things to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div> 
    <strong> unimportant text here </strong> 
    <span id="changeText">important text here</span>
</div>

$('#changeText').text= "I CHANGE THE TEXT";
```

Comment: In this case it sadly is not possible to add a ID or Class to the HTML content. thanks for your help!